# Unable to get the values from JSON Array and Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

In my Javascript and PHP, I've manage to do an .ajax call to get an array. However when I want to display the display the values of each object I'm unable to do so.

PHP:

```
$request =  '{"request_id":' .$requestId. ', "reqName":"' .$requestName. '", "reqSubject":' .json_encode($requestSubjects). '}';

array_push($requestArray, $request);

echo json_encode($requestArray);
```

So when I `console.log(data)` it looks like this:

```
["{"request_id":13, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","A Math"]}", "{"request_id":14, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","E Math"]}"]
```

When I `console.log(data[0])`, I'm able to get the first object:

```
{"request_id":13, "reqName":"Rin", "reqSubject":["English","A Math"]}
```

However when I want to get the values of the object like so, `console.log(data[0].request_id)`, it returns an `undefined`.

Would highly appreciate if someone could tell me what's wrong with my codes. Thank you.

---

Comment: Your response is JSON it means String. You should parse it with: var result=JSON.parse(data[0]); Then result.request_id will give you what you want..

Comment: it should be work ```data[0]["request_id"]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you are getting is in `json` format. You have to parse it first. Try with -

```
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data[0]); //parse json data
console.log(response.request_id);
```

Comment: I think this might be right, but an answer should explain why it is an answer and not just dump code at the reader.

Answer (score 2):

`["{"request_id":13,`
note the " directly after the [. That's not the output format of an array containing objects in the javascript console, but an array that contains strings.
And that's because of

```
$request =  '{"request_id":' .$requestId. ', "reqName":"' .$requestName. '", "reqSubject":' .json_encode($requestSubjects). '}';
```

in your php script. You're not building a hashmap/object here but a string. And it is encoded as such by json_encode.

Try it with

```
$request = array(
    "request_id" => $requestId,
    "reqName" => $requestName,
    "reqSubject" => $requestSubjects,
)
array_push($requestArray, $request);

echo json_encode($requestArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the objects to string.

Just try it out

```
$request =  {"request_id":"aaaa", "reqName":"bbbb", "reqSubject":"ccc"};
 alert(JSON.stringify($request.request_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your post you mentioned that

"However when I want to get the values of the object like so,
 console.log(data[0].request_id), it returns an undefined."

To treat the result as an object it should be parsed to JSON object by using JSON.parse() method
Otherwise you can use it as an array

data[0]["request_id"]

Comment: `data[0]["request_id"]` and `data[0].request_id` are equivalent in JS.

Comment: can you please give a proper solution to the problem.